# How do I convert eclipse App for phone?

Tags: android, eclipse

I have downloaded eclipse and the Android sdk and I have now used eclipse to design an android app which runs fine on the emulator. I have also downloaded and installed Kies for file transfer between PC and Samsung phone. I used Kies to download a free app from Android market and checked the format of the downloaded files, one is an ‘app file’, the other is ‘image files’. Do I have to somehow turn the saved files from my eclipse created app into the above file types for transfer to my phone? If so how? If not, which files do I transfer to my phone? 
Hope someone can help, apologies if I have missed something simple and obvious. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you're just looking to test/debug your app on your own phone, then you can do that straight from Eclipse's Run menu once you've set up your environment properly. See [Developing on a Device](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html) from the Android developer site.

There's also information on [signing](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html) and [publishing](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/preparing.html) your app to the Market.

Comment: Thank you Sixten Otto for the quick reply, I will try what you suggest. 
But, unless I am reading it wrong, it appears that using this method will not load the app onto the phone, only test it via the phone screen. 
The app I have created is a very simple drug calculation app that would be useful for me at my workplace, so I just want to load it onto my phone for my own use and not load it up to Android market.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to enable "Usb debugging mode" under settings\application in your phone. 
If you have the android sdk, the phone drivers and the eclipse android plugin properly setup you should be able to debug your application in your phone using eclipse.